# Selenium Python Finding and selecting a value from a dropdown box

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

```html
<div _ngcontent-shg-c319="" class="p-field p-grid p-col-12 p-lg-5"><label _ngcontent-shg-c319="" for="possession" class="p-col-12 p-mb-2 p-md-4 p-mb-md-0 asterisk-mark">Possession</label><div _ngcontent-shg-c319="" class="p-col-12 p-md-8"><p-dropdown _ngcontent-shg-c319="" id="possession" name="possession" placeholder="Select Possession..." class="ng-tns-c71-41 p-inputwrapper-filled ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty"><div class="ng-tns-c71-41 p-dropdown p-component p-dropdown-open"><div class="p-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c71-41"><input type="text" readonly="" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="listbox" class="ng-tns-c71-41" aria-label="P2023/3727403" aria-expanded="true"></div><span class="ng-tns-c71-41 p-dropdown-label p-inputtext ng-star-inserted">P2023/3727403<!----><!----><!----></span><!----><!----><!----><!----><div role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" class="p-dropdown-trigger ng-tns-c71-41" aria-expanded="true"><span class="p-dropdown-trigger-icon ng-tns-c71-41 pi pi-chevron-down"></span></div><div class="ng-trigger ng-trigger-overlayAnimation ng-tns-c71-41 p-dropdown-panel p-component ng-star-inserted" style="z-index: 1021; transform-origin: center top; top: 39px; left: 0px;"><!----><div class="p-dropdown-items-wrapper ng-tns-c71-41" style="max-height: 200px;"><ul role="listbox" class="p-dropdown-items ng-tns-c71-41"><!----><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="No possession" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">No possession</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3727403" aria-selected="true" class="p-dropdown-item p-highlight p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3727403</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3588342" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3588342</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3730522" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3730522</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3601448" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3601448</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3137601" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3137601</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3553326" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3553326</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3137761" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3137761</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3531862" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3531862</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3602070" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3602070</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3785536" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3785536</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3617018" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3617018</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3815911" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3815911</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3832874" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3832874</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3736603" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3736603</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3588724" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3588724</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3829477" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3829477</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3591267" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3591267</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3137703" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3137703</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3532987" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3532987</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3596191" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3596191</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3740835" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3740835</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3532992" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3532992</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3601447" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3601447</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3549426" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3549426</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3532993" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3532993</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3591252" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3591252</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3747727" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3747727</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3529504" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3529504</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3532991" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3532991</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3438132" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3438132</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3818936" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3818936</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3832462" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3832462</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3588431" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3588431</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3552753" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3552753</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3531822" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3531822</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3708700" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3708700</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3730523" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3730523</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3786352" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3786352</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3785601" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3785601</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3529483" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3529483</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3602202" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3602202</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3588402" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3588402</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3602205" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3602205</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3673531" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3673531</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3529503" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3529503</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3590730" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3590730</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3529505" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3529505</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3785535" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3785535</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3611184" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3611184</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3732728" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3732728</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3591211" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3591211</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3137681" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3137681</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3747751" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3747751</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3553199" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3553199</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3591210" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3591210</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3837919" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3837919</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3531842" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3531842</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3601449" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3601449</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3531861" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3531861</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><p-dropdownitem class="ng-tns-c71-41 ng-star-inserted" style=""><li role="option" pripple="" aria-label="P2023/3137622" aria-selected="false" class="p-dropdown-item p-ripple"><span class="ng-star-inserted">P2023/3137622</span><!----><!----><span class="p-ink"></span></li></p-dropdownitem><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----><!----></ul></div></div><!----></div></p-dropdown></div></div>
```

Can anyone help me generate the Selenium code to select P2023/3727403,

I've tried this and #Find the Possession element, send the loaded value and click it again

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/p-dynamicdialog/div/div/div[2]/bbwt-add-activity-modal/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/p-dropdown").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"").click()
time.sleep(3)
#driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/p-dynamicdialog/div/div/div[2]/bbwt-add-activity-modal/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/p-dropdown").click()
time.sleep(3)
```

It doesn't work, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you reformat the code snippet at the top into several lines to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below XPATH expression will locate the element(s) containing text **P2023/3727403**

```
//*[text()='P2023/3727403']
```

**Note:** In the HTML mark-up which you have shared I see 2 elements containing this text(P2023/3727403). So, if you want to locate the first element, use the below:

```
(//*[text()='P2023/3727403'])[1]
```

to locate the second element, use below:

```
(//*[text()='P2023/3727403'])[2]
```

Comment: Works amazing, thank you so much!